# how to insert $ in lstinline

Tags: markdown, tex, listings

when translate some code in lstinline, I find that

`\passthrough{\lstine!xxx!}`

I want to insert $, I know in latex should be

`lstinline !$\$$!`

however, I used in markdown, I input like

`` `$` => lstinline !$! ``

`` `$\$$` => lstinline !$\\$$! ``

anyone knows how to insert $ in markdown? Thank you.

ref:https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4713

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved the problem, https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4713 
by setting

`latex
\lstset{mathescape=false}`

now it seems that pandoc has a bug when open `mathescape=true`.